# Workflow draft state items are published

Tags: sitecore-client

We have items that are in draft state. When publishing it is pushed to the Web database.

Where we need to check and update the configuration?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824422/sitecore-workflow-publishing-item-in-draft-state), it might help you.

Comment: @DeepakGedia It is creating version in our end even it is in draft state.

Comment: @Astle when you edit this item in Content Editor or Experience Editor, do you see a yellow warning at the top saying something like "If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible..."?

Answer (score 1):

1. One of the potential reasons why it can happen is the `Draft` state itself.

There is a checkbox on every workflow state called `Final`. If your `Draft` state is marked as `Final`, it will be always published.

2. And second setting `Preview publishing targets` - if any of them is selected, items in this workflow state can be published to the selected preview publishing targets even though this state is not the `Final` workflow state.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

3. There may be also another version of the item which is already ready to be published. Check version selector in `Content Editor` to see other versions of the item:

[image]

4. One more potential reason: **workflows are disabled**.

Check those 2 in your code:

```
var workflowsEnabledInGeneral = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.Workflows.Enabled;

SiteContext site = Factory.GetSite("publisher");
var workflowsEnabledForPublisherSite = site != null && site.EnableWorkflow;
```

If any of them is false, workflow state will be ignored.

The first one is coming from your Sitecore license, second can be changed in Sitecore config and checked in `showconfig.aspx` page.

Comment: Hi @Marek, In the Draft item, final field is not marked and preview publishing targets also not selected.

Comment: Is there any other version of that item? What does version selector in `Content Editor` says (see updated answer)?

Comment: We have single version only.

Comment: See 4. in edited answer